# Extended Integers?

Tags: number-theory

If you google "Extended Reals", you will find lots of material.  The extended reals are the union of the real numbers and positive and negative infinity.  But if you google "Extended Integers" then literally nothing comes up.  Why is this?

Comment: Extended reals are useful in measure theory, but I didn't get when the extended integers are needed. It might be the reason why no one talks about extended integers.

Comment: Thanks for the response.    I believe I have a good use for extended integers.

Comment: There are many good uses for extended integers. (Search, for example, for $p$-adic valuations, where one commonly sets $v_p\left(0\right) = +\infty$; also search for tropical semirings and other objects.) It's just that noone uses such a generic name; after all, rational numbers, real numbers, complex numbers all have equal rights to the name of "extended integers".

Comment: Hi Darij.  Could you please explain how "Rational numbers" has a right to the name "extended integers"?  I apologize if this is a dumb question.

Comment: @user73063 They're a superset, so they're another way of "extending" the set.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: "Extended reals" usually means $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$, rather than (say) $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ which is called the "one point compactification of the reals". Have you seen any use for $\mathbb{Z}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$? (I do *not* mean to suggest they aren't used. I'm just curious.) Following your keywords, "tropical semiring", I saw that $\mathbb{Z}\cup\{+\infty\}$ is used.

Comment: @rgrig: I have not seen $\mathbb{Z} \cup \left\{-\infty, +\infty\right\}$ used much, I'm afraid. One problem with this set is that you cannot reasonably define addition on it (because what is $\left(-\infty\right) + \left(+\infty\right)$ ?).

Comment: @darijgrinberg: OK, thanks. $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ has the same problem and _is_ used, though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line